# Symfony 2 - could not able to insert json_array type variable

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

`json_array` type variable is not able to include to the database. The populated exception is as follow

```
(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException(code: 0): Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed at /var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/SimpleArrayType.php:51)"}
```

My entity class has this part for `json_array` type paramter.

```
/**
*
* @ORM\Column(name="street", type="json_array")
*/
private $street;
```

also I include to the db using entity manager.

```
$entityName->setStreet(
           array(
              'street_1' => $queueItem->street_1,
              'street_2' => $queueItem->street_2));

if($this->em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityState($entityName)) {
               $this->em->flush();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to dump the array you're passing to `setStreet`?

Comment: my var_dump is array(2) {
  'street_1' =>
  string(38) "address line 1"
  'street_2' =>
  string(10) "Office 101"
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `type="text"` or a own entity for multiple streets

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#text

Because:

1. `type="json_array"` is deprecated use `type="json"` http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#json-array
2. this type want a string that could be encoded, not an array